# 検索補完を実現したいです。JavaScriptのxhrで一つ一つの要素に処理を行うものを考えています。

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, http, xml

JavaScriptのxhrで取得したものから属性値を抽出したいのですが 
方法がよくわかりません。

```
<form name="f"> 
<input type="text" name="t" onkeyup="s()"> 
</form> 
<script async defer> 
    function s() {
      v = document.f.t.value;
      var x = new  XMLHttpRequest();
      x.addEventListener('load',function(ev) {
        document.getElementById('r').textContent = x.response;
      });
      x.open('GET','/complete?q=' + v);
      x.send();
    } 
</script> 
<p id="r"></p>
```

というソースコードでテキストフォームに例えば「あ」と入力すると

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<toplevel>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="アマゾン"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="明日の天気"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="アニメ"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="アニポ"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="アイコス"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="あ"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="嵐"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="アンパンマン"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="アスクル"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="青空エール"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
</toplevel>
```

このように表示されるのですがdata属性の値を抽出してforeachのようなことを行いたいです。 
お手数をおかけしますが、方法を教えて頂けるとありがたいです。
追加の希望で恐縮ですがjQueryなどライブラリーを使用しない方法を提示してください。

Comment: こちらがソースコードの部分に訂正です。

Comment: 正しくは    <form name="f"> <input type="text" name="t" onkeyup="s()"> 
</form> 
<script async defer> 
function s(){v=document.f.t.value;var x = new XMLHttpRequest();x.addEventListener('load',function(ev){document.getElementById('r').textContent = x.response;});x.open('GET','/complete?q='+v);x.send();} 
</script> 
<p id="r"></p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML文書から属性を取り出すにはDOMParser(もともとJavaScriptに入っています)を使います
参考: [クライアントサイドJavaScriptでXML文書のDOMをパースする](http://qiita.com/tom_konda/items/5e9824b38842615c9df1)

また、検索補完をするためには`datalist`要素を使います
参考: [<input autocomplete>－HTML5タグリファレンス](http://www.htmq.com/html5/input_autocomplete.shtml)

下記のコードようにすると補完できます

```
<form name="f"> 
<input type="text" name="t" onkeyup="s()" list="keyword"> 
<datalist id="keyword">
</datalist>
</form> 
<script async defer>
    var datalist = document.getElementById("keyword"); //datalistのDOMを取得
    function s() {
      v = document.f.t.value;
      var x = new  XMLHttpRequest();
      x.addEventListener('load',function(ev) {
        var parser = new DOMParser(); // DOMParserというものを使って変換します (標準ライブラリ)
        var dom = parser.parseFromString(x.response, "text/xml"); // x.responseの値をxmlとしてパース
        var suggestions = dom.getElementsByTagName("suggestion"); // data属性を持っているsuggestion要素だけを集める //data属性の値を入れる空の配列
        for (var i = 0; i < suggestions.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option"); // オプション要素を生成
            option.value = suggestions[i].getAttribute("data"); // seggesition要素のdata属性の値をoption要素のvalue属性に入れる
            datalist.appendChild(option); // option要素をdatalist要素に追加

        }

      });
      x.open('GET','/complete?q=' + v);
      x.send();
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: ご丁寧な説明ありがとうございます。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます

Comment: しつもんしたものです。forを使わないと難しいのですね。しかし、autocompleteに対応しているブラウザで実行しましたが表示されませんでした。対策がわからないのでそちらも教えてください。ご迷惑をおかけしました。

Comment: 上のようにコメントしましたがnew DomParserをnew DOMParserに変更することで検索補完ができるようになりました。

Comment: 大変な感動を覚えました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 検索候補の一部しか表示されない、繰り返し表示される問題を確認しました。端末の問題でしょうか。

Comment: 一部しか表示されないのはブラウザが先頭一致のもののみ表示することに起因するとわかりました。

Comment: コードのミス(`new DomParser`となっていた)のご指摘ありがとうございます。修正しました。
あと、この回答で解決していただけたならこの回答を`承認`(チェックマークをつける)していただけるとありがたいです。